# Parallel Arrays and reading from a file

Tags: java

I need help making a parallel array I need to read in from a textfile of strings and create a array of strings that adds each name once and increments repeated strings in an array of ints..... any ideas of how i can fix this code to do that?

```
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(new File("Cat.txt"));
    String category=sc.nextLine();
    int total=sc.nextInt();
    int[]totcat=new int[total];
    String[]names=new String[total];
    while(sc.hasNextLine())
    {
        String x=sc.nextLine();
        boolean b=false;
        int size=0;
        for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++)
        {
            if(x.equals(names[i]))
            {
                b=true;
                totcat[i]++;
            }
        }
        if(!b)
        {
            names[size]=x;
            totcat[p]++;
            size;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You declare the size (which I assume is `p`, although it really ought to be more descriptive, especially if you're asking others to look at your code) in the loop, instead of outside of it. So the size is always zero in the loop, so only the first element ever gets incremented.

Comment: so what should i do instead @jackarms

Comment: never mind i got it to work @jackarms

Comment: @user3196301 if you did not get your answer, lemme know so I can help you :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the line `if(names[j].equals(null))`. This will never evaluate to `true`, since for that to happen, `names[j]` would have to be `null`, and so it would instead throw a `NullPointerException`. The correct way to write it would be `if(names[j] == null)`.

A more elegant way would be to have another variable to keep track of how many strings you have in your array, so that if you don't find a repeated string (your `if(!b)` block), you can just add the string at the index indicated by the size variable, instead of having to go through the whole array looking for a `null` space.

Comment: How would i do that? @jackarms

Comment: Store the size in an `int`, and when you need to add a string, the size will tell you the index to put it in. Then increase the size and repeat.

Comment: and the results give me the wrong numbers when i ran the program it told me that each of the five strings was repeated only once but its supposed to give me 27 21 18 16 and 13 @jackarms

Comment: can you show me how to do that i still dont understand and im new to java programming @jackarms

Comment: Well I don't know what the input is, so I have no way of verifying those results. And I don't know how to explain it any simpler. Have an `int` called `size`, and set `names[size]` to the string you're adding, then increment `size`.

Comment: i did what you suggested but this times my results were 106 0 0 0 0 and 106 was the total....is there anyway you could directly look at my code and textfile?@jackarms

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to read a file with Strings that are delimited by line breaks, and you want to end up with a set of all Strings found in the file as well as a count of the number of times each String occurs in the file.

Rather than trying to build an array-based structure, I'd recommend using a Map. As you read each line in the source file you check the map to see if the String value already exists in the map. If so, you increment it's value (an int), if not, you add the String to the Map.

Something like this:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
  String line;
  while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    if(map.containsKey(line)) {
      Integer lineCount = map.get(line);
      map.put(line, lineCount++);
    } else {
      map.put(line, 1);
    }
  }
} catch(IOException ioe) {
  // Handle exception
}
```

Something to watch our for here is memory limitations. If the file you are reading is very large and/or your Java stack size is small, you may encounter OutOfMemoryExceptions.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use that for this assignment but do you know why my code isnt working  @velocoder

Comment: It would be useful if you would spell out your constraints more clearly in the question. If you must solve this problem using a pair of arrays, say so. You also say that you're reading from a "textfile of strings" yet based on "sc.nextInt()" you clearly expect to find a number in the file on the second line.

Comment: Also, please use descriptive variable names, that would make reading your code so much easier.

As @jackarms said, the "p" variable is going to be 0 on every iteration of the loop. Move the "p" variable outside of the while loop and you should see better results.